# Search and replace entire line after 1st match using SED?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have a file using the following format:

```
M104 S200
M107
M104 S250
M110
M104 S275
```

I'm trying to find a way to match let's say the second occurrence of `M104` and rewrite the entire line to something else ALSO containing `M104`.

I've tried

```
sed 's/^M104/s/.*/M104 S300/' file - but it replaces all instances of M104
sed '0,/M104/s//M104 S200/' file - leaves the trailing text on the line
```

- a few other variations that are giving me unexpected results.  Any help?  ;)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I suggest to use `awk` for this job.

Comment: Expected result should be a search for 1st, 2nd, or 3rd instance of "M104", then I can replace the entire line to something like "M104 S190" or my own value ignoring the current S numbers.

I'm familiar with AWK/SED but even after 2 hours of searching google haven't found a solution yet ;)

Comment: Please edit question and add your desired output (**no description**, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3):

If you have Perl, I'd do something like this:

```
$ perl -pe 'if (/M104/) { $i++; if($i == 2) { $_ = "M104 S999\n" } } ' test.txt
M104 S200
M107
M104 S999
M110
M104 S275
```

I.e. if `/M104/` matches, increment `$i`, then check if `$i` is equal to 2, and if so, replace the current line (including the trailing newline, `\n`)

You could use `s/^M104.*/.../` in the last part if you want to use a sed-like substitution there.

Perl has the sed-like `-i[extension]` option for in-place changes with or without a backup file.

Or passing the key values through env vars (makes scripting easier):

```
n=2 repl="S999" perl -pe 'if (/M104/) { $i++; if($i == $ENV{n}) { $_ = "M104 " . $ENV{repl} . "\n" } } ' test.txt
```

<sub>(or if you like chaining more than nesting, something like `perl -pe '/M104/ and $i++ and $i == 2 and $_ = "M104 S999\n" ' test.txt`.)</sub>

---

or in awk:

```
$ awk '/M104/ { i++; if (i == 2) $0 = "M104 S999"; } 1' test.txt
```

But there's no standard in-place option for awk.

Comment: This gives the expected result, however I'm totally new to perl, does it have a -i (interactive) command to write the result to file like SED?

Comment: @JV, yep, `perl -i.bak -pe ...`. (I think `-i` is for "in-place" here)

Comment: wow that worked great!  I may have to study up on perl a little more as this seems very effective.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your (failed) attempts imply that your `sed` version allows the `0` for the start of a range (not all `sed`s do). If so, try

```
sed -rn '0,/^M104/{p;b;}; 0,/(^M104).*/ s//\1 S300/; p' file
M104 S200
M107
M104 S300
M110
M104 S275
```

The idea is to apply the address range twice: the first range will find and print lines unaltered up to the first match. The second range will then substitute the next match. Again, not all `sed` versions accept the second range's start address when it's already consumed by the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **GNU** `sed`, you can use the `-z` option to process the whole file in one buffer and use the number flags to the `s` command to substitute the *n*th occurence:

```
sed -zE 's/(^|\n)M104[^\n]*/\1M104 S300/2'
```

The `2` tells `sed` to replace the second match.

Note that I use extended regular expressions (option `-E`), so I can match for either a line break or the beginning of the file and reinsert the match (`\1`) to keep the line break.

The **portable** version  can't use the `-z` option and is not allowed to use `[^\n]` for "everything but newline", so we use the hold bufer to collect lines and expect lines to contain nothing but printable characters:

```
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/(^|\n)M104[[:print:]]*/\1M104 S300/2'
```

Also note that the buffer may be too big for very large files.